# Invalid Conversion Error from JSON data handler?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to read URL using dataTask class and I got hit into a wired error, can someone help me decode that please

ERROR:

Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'

[image: Screenshot of the ERROR]

```
 let url = URL(string: source)!
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
     session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print ((err?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }
        let json = try !JSON(data : data!)
        for i in json["articles"] {
            let title = i.1["title"].stringValue
            let description = i.1["description"].stringValue
            let url = i.1["url"].stringValue
            let image = i.1["urlToImage"].stringValue
            let id = i.1["publishedAt"].stringValue
            
            self.datas.append(dataType(id: String, title: <#T##String#>, desc: <#T##String#>, url: <#T##String#>, image: <#T##String#>))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the return  and replace by an else           if err != nil {
            print ((err?.localizedDescription)!)
        } else {
           let json = try !JSON(data : data!)
Have a look here for a tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/3244963-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this is not a throwing function, so you can't say `try` directly within the function. Instead, put the `try` inside the `do` part of a `do...catch` construct.

(Also fix that space between `try` and the exclamation mark. Actually that might fix the whole problem right there: `try! JSON(...`. But in general, don't do that; say `try` without an exclamation and *catch* the error so if there *is* an error you can find out what it is. Saying `try!` throws away valuable information.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `do` block whenever you deal with a throwing function. In your case, `JSON(data: data!)` might throw an error.

All throwing functions deal with errors that can be caught in the `catch` block. In the `catch` block, you would log the errors somewhere or handle them accordingly, like showing an alert to the user with steps to follow based on the error.

The following will remove the Xcode error:

```swift
let url = URL(string: source)!
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, err) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    do {
        let json = try JSON(data : data!)
        for i in json["articles"] {
            let title = i.1["title"].stringValue
            let description = i.1["description"].stringValue
            let url = i.1["url"].stringValue
            let image = i.1["urlToImage"].stringValue
            let id = i.1["publishedAt"].stringValue

            self.datas.append(dataType(id: id, title: title, desc: description, url: url, image: image))

        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```